# algorithm to predict numeric values with sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I'm new to ML and trying to learn it. I scraped information (using python) from a website where people try to sell their cars. I put data in a pandas data frame. Now I'm wondering how should I predict a car's price according to its manufacturing year and its mileage! I drew some plots and there is a correlation between price-year and price-mileage!

[image: Mileage to Price Plot]

[image: Year to Price Plot]

Comment: I recommend Jeremy Howard's "Practical Machine Learning for Coders" course -- he works through an example similar to this using random forest regressors in scikit-learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try linear regression with sci-kit learn. You can use both year and mileage as predictors for price.